# Simple way to shuffle deck of cards

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I'm looking for a simple way to shuffle my deck of cards. I have finished the deck, what's a simple way to create a function that shuffles the 52 cards? I'm not looking for complex ways to shuffle, I prefer code that I can read with ease. I've tried to put rand() on the `cout` part, but it just randomizes both suits and faces and I get the wrong cards.

```
struct Card 
    {
        int value;
        char suit;
    };
Card cards[52];   //global variables

int main()
{
    int play;

    shuffleDeck();
    cout << endl<<endl;
    cout << "---------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "|Welcome to The Game Of 31| " << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Would you like to play? (1 for 'YES', 0 for 'NO'): ";
    cin >> play;
    if (play == 1) { shuffleDeck(); }
    else { cout << "See yaa!"; exit(0); }



}


void shuffleDeck() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        cards[i].value = i % 13; // 13 values
        if (cards[i].value == 0) {
            cards[i].value = 1;
        }
        else if (cards[i].value == 1) {
            cards[i].value = 2;
        }
        else if (cards[i].value == 2) {
            cards[i].value = 3;
        }
        else if (cards[i].value == 3) {
            cards[i].value = 4;
        }
        else if (cards[i].value == 4) {
            cards[i].value = 5;
        }
        else if (cards[i].value == 5) {
            cards[i].value = 6;
        }
        else if (cards[i].value == 6) {
            cards[i].value = 7;
        }
        else if (cards[i].value == 7) {
            cards[i].value = 8;
        }
        else if (cards[i].value == 8) {
            cards[i].value = 9;
        }
        else if (cards[i].value == 9) {
            cards[i].value = 10;
        }
        else if (cards[i].value == 10) {
            cards[i].value = 10;

        }
        else if (cards[i].value == 11) {
            cards[i].value = 10;
        }
        else if (cards[i].value == 12) {
            cards[i].value = 10;
        }


        cards[i].suit = i / 13;// 4 suits
        if (cards[i].suit == 0) {
            cards[i].suit = 'D';
        }
        else if (cards[i].suit == 1) {
            cards[i].suit = 'H';
        }
        else if (cards[i].suit == 2) {
            cards[i].suit = 'C';
        }
        else if (cards[i].suit == 3) {
            cards[i].suit = 'S';
        }
    }

    for (int count = 0; count < 52; count++) {
        int count2 = 0;
        cout << " | " << cards[count].value;
        cout << cards[count].suit << " | ";

        if (count == 13) { cout << endl; }
        else if (count == 26) { cout << endl; }
        else if (count == 39) { cout << endl; }
        else if (count == 52) { cout << endl; }
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
void shuffleDeck() {
    theDeck();
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());

    std::shuffle(cards, cards + 52, g);

    for (int count = 0; count < 52; count++) {
        int count2 = 0;
        cout << " | " << cards[count].value;
        cout << cards[count].suit << " | ";

        if (count == 13) { cout << endl; }
        else if (count == 26) { cout << endl; }
        else if (count == 39) { cout << endl; }
        else if (count == 52) { cout << endl; }
    }
```

Comment: Use [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)

Comment: What is that???

Comment: It's a function that shuffles a set of data.

Comment: It randomly shuffles items in a container. Exactly what you want unless this is an academic assignment that prohibits you from using the c++ standard library.

Comment: `cards[i].value = std::min(10, (i % 13) + 1); cards[i].suit = "DHCS"[i / 13];` to replace your long initialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [shuffle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) the cards like this:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 g(rd());

std::shuffle(cards, cards + 52, g);
```

Don't worry *too much* about the 1st 2 lines. You can think of it as a way to ensure that the cards are shuffled *well*.

Comment: What's the library for this?

Comment: I've added the link in the answer. It's in `<algorithm>`.

Comment: Look at the example code in that link. This is directly from the `c++` standard library. It should be valid for a compiler that supports the 2011 standard or greater.